# Why the wrong words of libreoffice web displayed on my firefox?

Tags: firefox

When I open http://www.libreoffice.org/about-us/who-are-we/, in the web so many character lost in the word, what is the matter with my Firefox?

[image]

Comment: Try pressing `Ctrl`+`F5`.

Comment: please me the reason.

Comment: It will force-reload the page, not using any of the browser's (possibly corrupted) cache.